# How can i do this Data Binding in the HTML file component with Angular and Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

How can i see in my simple component.html file the information about the variable: cityInfo?
This is the component.html file, it's a very basic component, but i want to do the Data Binding with the component.ts file.
How can i do?

```
<div>
  <p>
    weather works! {{cityInfo}}
  </p>
</div>
```

And this is my component.ts.
With the getWeather(city), I do an http request and return me a JSON file.

```
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  public cityVisual: City;

  constructor(
    private weather: WeatherService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  weatherCity(city: string) {
    this.weather.getWeather(city).subscribe(resp => {
      this.cityVisual = resp;
      console.log(this.cityVisual.name);

    });
  }
}
```

I want to see in my component.html file the "weather work! nameCity" output
How can i do this?
Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd bind the city name:

```
<div>
  <p>
    weather works! {{cityVisual.name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: But i receive this error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Where are you calling that service? I don't see that part of the code. Undefined means that the service is either not called or service is not responding with value.

Comment: In getWeather with the get http request, and i receive a JSON file with the city information, in that case name (string)

Comment: How can i update the cityVisual variable after i obtain the information?

Comment: the weatherCity function you have is good enough, it will assign the value to cityVisual. However, I don't see where you are calling it from?

Comment: I call the weatherCity('Some city') in the main.component, and in the main.component i optain the city with an input, so i call the weatherCity

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get `name` of `cityVisual` only when it is define;
You can easy make it by add `?` after `cityVisual`.
You got this error, because `weatherCity` method is async. and it `cityVisual` is undefine when html init. Try code under this text.

```
<div>
  <p>
    weather works! {{cityVisual?.name}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i update the cityVisual after i obtai the information?

Comment: You need to call `this.weatherCity('Some city')` somewhere in your code, like in `ngOnInit` for example

Comment: I call the weatherCity('Some city') in the main.component, and in the main.component i optain the city with an input, so i call the weatherCity

Comment: console.log(this.cityVisual) What show you? in your method.Can you show data what you get after HTTP request i mean you JSON

Comment: There is a method to update the cityVisual variable when i obtain this information?

Answer (score 0):

Your function `weatherCity()` is never being called. That's why nothing is being rendered on your page and your console returns an error.

Try calling it inside your `ngOnInit` block:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherCity('Washington');
}
```

Or bind it to a button in HTML:

```
<button (click)="this.weatherCity('Washington')">Load Washington</button>
```

.. and check for results in your browser console.

If you get a result there, you can bind to that result by using 
`{{ cityVisual.name }}` anywhere in your HTML.

Make sure you are only rendering the name if `cityVisual` is actually defined by putting your code in an `*ngIf` statement:

```
<p *ngIf="cityVisual">
    Weather works! {{cityVisual.name}}
</p>
```

**SIDENOTE:** Don't forget to unsubscribe to your `WeatherService` if you are done fetching cities, or you will have a memory leak.

Consider storing the subscription in a variable (e.g. `citySubscription$`) so you can call `.unsubscribe()` at `ngOnDestroy` (or whenever else you want to kill the subscription)

Comment: I call in main.component, and i obtain the city with an input

Comment: Like this:

getWeather() {
      this.weatherComponent.weatherCity(this.city);
    }
  }

Comment: Your weatherCity() function in weatherComponent does not return anything. It only sets the cityVisual object inside weatherComponent, so it will never make it to main.component. Update your function so you return the result of the WeatherService call. Then make sure you use that result inside your getWeather() function in main.component, e.g. by setting it to this.result.

Comment: Maybe if i delete the weather.component and i work only in main.component is a bad idea? 
Because the situation is this: I have the main component that call the weather.component that call the weather.service that get the http request.

It is good to programming in this way or no?
It have sense?

Comment: If it works it works, but it sort of defeats the purpose of your service. If I were you I would indeed import the service into your main component and then feed the data to your child components